# Jquery AJAX success doesn't work in Firefox (only in this script other works well)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I've 4 script with ajax but one of them doesn't works in Firefox.
It put an alert in success & it dosen't work too.
I've no error message but nothing happen.
It works very well in IE & Chrome.

Here my code :

```
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$.ajax(
  {
    type: "GET",
    url: "../processeur.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,
    cache:false,
    success: function(response)
    {
      alert("success");

      var options ="";              
      if(response != null)
      {
        for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++)
        {
          options +="<option value = '"+response.data[i]+"'>"+response.data[i];"</option>";
        }
      }                      

      $("#Liberation tbody").append
      (
        "<tr>"+            
        "<td align='center'><input class='liberationL' name='liberationL' type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td align='center'><input class='serviceL' name='serviceL' type='text'/></td>"+
        //liste déroulante des codes projets destinataires
        "<td align='center'>"+"<select class='codest' name ='codest' id=listecodes >"+"<option>Aucun</option>"+options+"</select>"+"</td>"+
        //"<td align='center'><input class='dateL' name='dateL' type='text'/><span><br>jj-mm-AAAA</span></td>"+
        "<td align='center'><input type='text' class='dateL' id='DateF' name='dateL' onclick='javascript:onCalendar_click();'/></td>"+
        "<td align='center'><input class='montantL' name='montantL' type='text'/></td>"+           
        //liste déroulante des types de mouvements            
        "<td align='center'>"+"<select class='mouvementL' name='mouvementL'>"+"<option value='lc'>LC(-)</option>"+"<option value='vc'>VC(+)</option>"+"<option value='ci'>CI</option>"+"</select>"+"</td>"+
        "<td align='center'>"+
        "<img src='../images/enregistrer.png' class='btnEnregistrerLiberation'"+"style='cursor: pointer;'/>"+' '+"<img src='../images/supprimer.png' class='btnSuppLiberation'"+"style='cursor: pointer;'/>"+"</td>"+
        "</tr>"
      );
      $(".btnEnregistrerLiberation").bind("click", EnregistrerLiberation); 
      $(".btnSuppLiberation").bind("click", SupprimerLib);
    },
    failure: function()
    {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
```

Here my php code, where data is encoded with json_encode :

```
include './BD/T_mouvements.php';
include '../sql.php';
require './jsonwrapper/jsonwrapper.php';

$idProg = $_GET['idProg']; 
$exercice = $_GET['exercice'];

$array = array();
$liste = selectionnerListePro($exercice, $idProg);

echo json_encode(array('data'=>$liste));

exit();
```

Comment: Did you try only added alert inside success function and remove other codes?

Comment: Yes & it still doesn't work

Comment: @SarangaR I added php code

Comment: did you try to throw an error server-side to see if the fail handler is working? Also, the error handler option is `error`, not `failure`.

Comment: @LynxWeb you can check it with your browser console. if ajax request is working or not.

Comment: ok I replace failure by error & now my alert("error") works

Comment: @SarangaR my result in console is :

GET http://ld2apa002t/portefeuille/modifications/processeur.php?exercice=2011&idProg=4&_=1483526394297
 
200 OK
  31ms

Comment: And my response is good : 

{"data":["DEV-SID","ENTREPOTDUI","HYDROGEOL","MES-TEMPS","MET-ENTREPO","MIG-BO\/XI","SID-AMODG","SID-ARCHID"
,"SID-DSI","SID-FNGE","SID-OT-POL","SID-PILOTAG","SID-USAGRH","SIG-3D","SIG-ALTERNA","SIG-BDTOPO","SIG-CAO-DAO"
,"SIG-DON-PDI","SIG-DONNEES","SIG-ORTHO","SIG-PLATGEO","SIG-STRUCTU","SIG-TOURNEE","SIG-WEB-PDI","STAT-CREDOC"
]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my problem.
In fact, my code was good but the bug was in my sql.php

The guy who coding before me, forget a ";"...

Thanks everybody :)